# Taking values from one multidimensional array and putting it in the other multidimensional array based on matching value from first key

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays, $full_list and $only_titles with matching value based on first key.

$full_list:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => samsung-a40 
            [1] => Samsung A40 Phone
            [2] => 
            [3] => 21
            [4] => 334234
            [5] => 0          
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => samsung-a72
            [1] => Galaxy A72 Phone
            [2] => 
            [3] => 230
            [4] => 239049
            [5] => 0    
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => lg-k61
            [1] => LG K61 Phone 
            [2] => 
            [3] => 22
            [4] => 249582
            [5] => 0    
        )


  etc...
```

`$only_titles`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => samsung-a40 
            [1] => Black Phone Case For Samsung A40               
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => lg-k61
            [1] => Red Case LG K61 Phone            
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => samsung-a72
            [1] => Folding Phone Case for Galaxy A72 Phone          
        )
   
  etc...
```

I want to take value from second key from $only_title array (its basicaly long product title) and replace it in the `$full_list` array:

`$final_result`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => samsung-a40
            [1] => Black Phone Case For Samsung A40   // title from $only_titles
            [2] => 
            [3] => 21
            [4] => 334234
            [5] => 0          
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => samsung-a72
            [1] => Folding Phone Case for Galaxy A72 Phone   // title from $only_titles     
            [2] => 
            [3] => 230
            [4] => 239049
            [5] => 0    
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => lg-k61
            [1] => Red Case LG K61 Phone  // title from $only_titles
            [2] => 
            [3] => 22
            [4] => 249582
            [5] => 0    
        )
  etc...
```

I have tried `array_replace_recursive()`, but the problem with this is that it expects that the order of subarrays are the same. But as you can see in both arrays the second subarrays dont match. With `array_replace_recursive()` i get the second subarray wrong:

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => samsung-a72
        [1] => Red Case LG K61 Phone  // this is wrong
        [2] => 
        [3] => 230
        [4] => 239049
        [5] => 0    
    )
```

How can I check if values from first key match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can utilize `array_map` and `array_search` for your task.

```
$items = array_map(function($item) use ($only_titles) {
  $index = array_search($item[0], array_column($only_titles, 0));
  if($index === false) return;

  $item[1] = $only_titles[$index][1]; 
  return $item;
}, $full_list);
```

`array_map()` takes `$full_list` and iterate each item as `$item`,
then for each item, we look for the matching title with `array_search()`
It will return an index from `$only_titles`.
We can use `$index` to reference and assign the long title to item.

The result are in `$items`

Comment: WIl this code work only if both of arrays ($full_list and $only_titles) have matching count of keys?

Comment: @PeterG yes, you are right, if array_search() can't find the matching key, it will return false, which can be easily checked.

Answer (score 0):

This script will help you to solve your problem

```php
<?php

$full_array = [
    [
        'samsung-a40',
        'Samsung A40 Phone',
        null,
        21,
        334234,
        0,
    ],
    [
        'samsung-a72',
        'Galaxy A72 Phone',
        null,
        230,
        239049,
        0,
    ],
];

$only_titles = [
    [
        'samsung-a40',
        'Black Phone Case For Samsung A40',
    ],
    [
        'samsung-a72',
        'Red Case LG K61 Phone  ',
    ],
];

$formattedOnlyTitles = [];
foreach ($only_titles as $value) {
    $formattedOnlyTitles[$value[0]] = $value[1];
}

$fullArrayWithNewTitle = [];
foreach ($full_array as $value) {
    if (isset($formattedOnlyTitles[$value[0]])) {
        $value[1] = $formattedOnlyTitles[$value[0]];
    }

    $fullArrayWithNewTitle[] = $value;
}

print_r($fullArrayWithNewTitle);
```

**output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => samsung-a40
            [1] => Samsung A40 Phone
            [2] => 
            [3] => 21
            [4] => 334234
            [5] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => samsung-a72
            [1] => Galaxy A72 Phone
            [2] => 
            [3] => 230
            [4] => 239049
            [5] => 0
        )
)
```

First I change the format of the `title_only` var to make is easy to work with it in the next foreach

```
$formattedOnlyTitles = [];
foreach ($only_titles as $value) {
    $formattedOnlyTitles[$value[0]] = $value[1];
}
```

In the next foreach I just check the title with my new formatted title_only array

```
if (isset($formattedOnlyTitles[$value[0]])) {
    $value[1] = $formattedOnlyTitles[$value[0]];
}
```

And then change the title if I need

Comment: What if $only_titles array is smaller than $full_array. Would be the best way to use else statement and unset($value) in foreach. And then outside foreach use array_filter($fullArrayWithNewTitle) and array_values($fullArrayWithNewTitle) to clean the gaps or is there a simpler approach?

Comment: You can implement in the way that you think is better but IMHO my script is simple and ok right now and easy to understand too